# Go: How to check if a struct property was explicitly set to a zero value?

Tags: go

```
type Animal struct {
    Name string
    LegCount int
}

snake := Animal{Name: "snake", LegCount: 0}
worm := Animal{Name: "worm"}
```

**Question:** How can I check `snake` and `worm` after they've been set, to tell that:

1. `snake` was explicitly set with a `LegCount` of 0.
2. The `worm`'s `LegCount` was not explicitly set (and therefore based off of its default value)?

Comment: You can't with what you've shown. What is setting the values? Is it up to the programmer or via a package like json, database/sql?

Comment: @JimB: Thank you.  I'm going to be processing data from an API.  I'm assuming there's a way to do this with Unmarshal but I didn't want to make the scope of the question too large.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is simply impossible to distinguish.

If you are unmarshalling data from XML or JSON, use pointers.

```
type Animal struct {
    Name *string
    LegCount *int
}
```

You will get `nil` values for absent fields.

You can use the same convention in your case.

Comment: Thank you Grzegorz!  Very helpful.