# How to check if a field was explicitly set in a custom resource

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-custom-resources, kubernetes-operator, operator-sdk

**Update:**
I found that my code actually working. The reason that reconcile loop get `false` at first is because I have another operator existing in my cluster and doing boolean flipping automatically. After deleted that operator, my code works as expected.

---

This question is related with Kubernetes and Operator-SDK. Let's say I have a Custom Resource which spec is shows as following:

```
apiVersion: my.example.com/v1alpha1
kind: MyStore
metadata:
  name: mystore
spec:
  name: "sample-store"
  address: "sample-address"
  zip: "sample-zip"
  open: true
```

Where the last field `open` is boolean type used to indicate whether the store is open or not. In reconcile loop of my operator, I would like to know whether a CR of `MyStore` kind was explicitly set value of `open` field. For example:

1. If the value CR's `open` field has been explicitly set as `true` or `false`, then reconcile loop should take this value directly.
2. If the CR does not have `open` field explicitly set, or this field is not existing, reconcile loop should consider the default value of `open` as `true`.

Currently I tried this way, which is set the type of `open` field as pointer of boolean in my struct:

```
type MyStoreSpec struct {
    Name         string   `json:"name"`
    Address      string   `json:"address"`
    Zip          string   `json:"zip"`
    Open         *bool    `json:"open"` // Here I use *bool as type
}


type MyStore stuct {
    metav1.TypeMeta   `json:",inline"`
    metav1.ObjectMeta `json:"metadata,omitempty"`

    Spec   MyStoreSpec   `json:"spec,omitempty"`
}
```

Then in reconcile loop I check the existing of `open` field like this:

```
store := &examplev1beta1.MyStore{}
r.client.Get(context.TODO(), request.NamespacedName, store)
if store.Spec.Open == nil {
    a := true
    store.Spec.Open = &a
}
```

The idea of above code is to check whether the pointer of `open` field exists: if pointer is null, set `true` to `open` field. And the idea is from this question [Go: How to check if a struct property was explicitly set to a zero value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014343/go-how-to-check-if-a-struct-property-was-explicitly-set-to-a-zero-value)

But above code is not working as I expected: if  `open` field of a CR is not exists (not have value be explicitly set), the value of `store.Spec.Open` will be parsed as `false` but not `nil`.

Is there any other ways to do the field value checking?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `omitempty` with your json tag.

```
type MyStoreSpec struct {
    Name         string   `json:"name"`
    Address      string   `json:"address"`
    Zip          string   `json:"zip"`
    Open         *bool    `json:"open,omitempty"` // Here I use *bool as type
}
```

Rest of the code should work.

Comment: I tried your solution but adding `omitempty` still not working, do you have any further thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Is the source code available in github? I could try making some changes.

Comment: I found the reason of why my code doesn't not working, please see update in my question.